# How to increase memory usage in Python in Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pbs

I am running a loop for finding out optimum parameter set for a random forest classifier in scikit-learn. I ma allocating 32 GB memory in the script but the program is using only 300 MB memory. Is there any way to increase the memory usage? Usage summary is as follows.

```
Cpus requested:          8 :          Cpus Used:       1.38
      Cpu Time:   00:01:02 :        Cpu percent:      17.2%
 Mem requested:     32.0GB :           Mem used:    283.3MB
                           :        Mem percent:       0.9%
```

Comment: What code did you use to try allocating 32 GB?

Comment: @ahota I am using a pbs script. Corresponding code is as follows.

`#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=1:mem=4GB`

Comment: I meant what you're using in Python to try allocating memory. To allocate dummy memory, I would do something like `big_string = ' ' * 100000`